# Strange problem of apostrophe in communicating with PHP script from Android

Tags: php, android, apostrophe

I am communicating with PHP web services in Android application. All the requests send from android are encoded with UTF-8 and the php scripts decodes it with utf-8.

But when any request is send with apostrophe ' the decode function of php doesn't seem to work the way it should.

For example, if I send the request as "Today's Horoscope" then its utf-8 encode will be "Today%27s+Horoscope". I tried to decode this with Android and it was successful. But in php it gives the same text after decoding.

The database is MySql. Is this a problem with database or php? I am not sure about it but is there any workaround to this problem?

Regards

Sunil

Answer (score 2):

This is not UTF-8 encoding, it's called URL or [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_encoding). Try running the data through [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/urldecode) before inserting it into the data base.

Comment: In PHP we have used the same thing i.e urldecode() but still the problem persists. Can you let me know what is the problem?

Comment: @sunil please show the code you are using to insert the data.

Comment: That's the problem I don't have access to the PHP code. Can you let me know whether its decoding issue or inserting into MySQl?

Comment: @sunil I'm afraid that is impossible to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Can you provide me a sample where you have used urldecoding and inserting into mysql? It will be of great help if you can.

Comment: @sunil a simple `$string = $_POST["string"]; $string = urldecode($string);` ... and then insert into the database using the DB of your choice. If you're using old style mySQL functions instead of PDO, don't forget ` $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);`

Answer (score 1):

```
urldecode(rawurldecode("Today%27s+Horoscope"));
```

as Pekka pointed out `urldecode` is sufficient in this case, this is mainly (overdone) precaution since I've seen `urldecode` failing

Comment: Is the `rawurldecode` really necessary though? Doesn't `urlencode()` handle both things?

Comment: You're right but I've seen cases where only both gave the proper solution, no idea why but in this case, `urldecode()` is enough. I just always use both to make sure...

Comment: if you have a % sign in text double decoding will break your text.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example in the php code and couldn't get the error as you mentioned.

```
$str = "Today's Horoscope";

echo $str; //Today's Horoscope

echo "Encoded: ".urlencode($str); //Encoded: Today%27s+Horoscope

echo "Decoded: ".urldecode($str); //Decoded: Today's Horoscope
```

If you would like to escape the quotes before inserting to the database use
`mysql_real_escape_string($str);`